# Unexpected value after passing raw mutable pointer to C FFI

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to create an FFI for a C function that takes a pointer to a struct and modifies it. I've tested the C code and gotten the values that I am expecting, but when I try and print the values from Rust I get completely different results. The element in question is a slice of u32.

The code looks something like this:

C:

```c
struct my_struct {
    uint64_t len;
    uint32_t state[4];
    int count;
};

int modify_struct(struct my_struct *x) 
{
    // modify here

    // prints the expected values
    uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)x->state;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%02x", bytes[i]);
}
```

Rust:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    length: u64,
    state: [u32; 4],
    count: libc::c_int
}

extern "C" {
    fn modify_struct(x: *mut MyStruct) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = MyStruct::default();
    unsafe { modify_struct(&mut x); }

    for i in 0..4 {
        println!("{:08x}", x.state[i]); // the values here differ from what the C code prints
    }
}
```

I print the value in C right before returning to Rust, and then print in Rust right after and the values are completely different.

Comment: What exactly do you expect, and what do you see from C and Rust?

Comment: What does the "modify here" part do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. It wasn't a problem in the FFI or C code, I was getting tripped up on endianess. I've edited the code above so it's more clear where the issue is (and better reflects the actual code).

##### Problem

I realized that when I print in Rust, I'm concatenating the actual 32-bit numbers together:

```rust
for i in 0..4 {
    println!("{:08x}", x.state[i]); // the values here differ from what the C code prints
}
```

But what I was unknowingly looking for was the exact (little endian) order in memory, which the C code was printing like so:

```
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)x->state;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02x", bytes[i]);
```

##### Solution

The solution for me was to change the way Rust represents the struct from:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    length: u64,
    state: [u32; 4],
    count: libc::c_int
}
```

to:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    length: u64,
    state: [u8; 16],
    count: libc::c_int
}
```

Which allows me to access the data in the exact byte order I'm looking for.

Comment: This Neophyte may be ready for the [unsafe door](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-koans/2408).  Seriously, good recognizing the difference here, though you may want to consider [transmuting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) the array (or rather a pointer to the array) before printing, rather than changing the struct representation.